# Invalid Assembly XML File

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to read the XML Documentation file (C#) using this ocde - 
            Type classType = typeof(Point);

```
        string documentationFileLocation = classType.Assembly.CodeBase;
        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(documentationFileLocation) && documentationFileLocation.StartsWith("file:///") )
        {
            documentationFileLocation = documentationFileLocation.Replace(".exe",".xml");
            documentationFileLocation = documentationFileLocation.Replace("file:///","");
            if(File.Exists(documentationFileLocation))
            {

                XElement document = XElement.Load(documentationFileLocation);
                // Some Code Logic Here using LINQ
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Go to Project Properties->Build and check 'XML Documentation file'");
```

I have a LINQ Query after XElement document = XElement.Load(sr) which dosen`t work,
So I put a breakpoint in the LINQ Query and I am getting this error - 
XmlException - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

How I can fix it?

***Edit:Changed the code a little - just deleted StreamReader***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `XDocument.Load()` instead of using `XElement`? If the file begins with an XML declaration `<?xml ...`, you might get this error when trying to load an element from it.

Edit: the file you pasted on pastebin has no encoding specified. Can you try to open this file in notepad and re-save it as ANSI, the see if it loads? Just to make sure that we don't have an encoding or BOM problem.

Comment: Tried using XDocument.Load() and still getting this error,and yes the file starts with "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>"

Comment: The problem is that this file is automatically generated by visual studio ( Project Properties -> Build -> XML Documentation file)

Comment: Yes, I know. But as I wrote, this is to diagnose the issue, so that we know how to proceed...

Comment: The same error,I think that I will be saved without BOM because Visual Studio Regenerate this file every build that I am doing.

Comment: I downloaded the pastebin and I can load it with `XDocument` just fine! So there is something else which is wrong somehow...

Comment: Tried again - Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd()) using StreamReader with encoding of Encoding.UTF8 and I get the xml file content but with XElement of XDocument I am getting this error!!!

Comment: It really hates me =X  "XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd()); " The same error =X

Comment: Worked :) Just Changed other line of code from document.Elements("member") to document.Element("members").Elements("member")

Answer (score 2):

Well, it sounds like it simply isn't a valid XML file.

If you print out the result of `sr.ReadToEnd()` instead of calling `XElement.Load`, what does it look like? If you try to load the file into an XML editor, what happens?

Btw, it's better to use a `using` statement than calling `Dispose` explicitly: with your current code, the `StreamReader` isn't disposed if `Load` throws an exception.

Finally, is there any reason you're not just using `XElement.Load(documentationFileLocation)`?

Comment: I am doing - Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd()) and I am getting empty screen,And I checked twice that the file exists at documentationFileLocation.And I deleted StreamReader and added XElement.Load(documentationFileLocation) and still getting the problem,And I didn`t have a special reason to use StreamReader

Comment: @Yosy: Well, it certainly sounds like an empty file. Did you try loading the file into an XML editor?

Comment: Yes,Tried using notepad and Visual C# Express 2010,Here is the xml file contents - http://pastebin.com/YTTS6vcf